# Why git is committing files not in my staging area?

Tags: git, commit

I select some files with `git add`. I verify them with `git status`:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    modified:   Module2/test/user/UserIT.java
    modified:   Module2/pom.xml
```

If I check with `git diff --cached`, I see the right content. But then, I commit with: `git commit -m"My message"`, and when I look in my commit with `git log -p -1`, I see:

```
commit fdfeb44fd6fa31e3495064c06777ef4587d3c76f (HEAD -> master)
Author: Orto <Orto@abc.com>
Date:   Tue Sep 24 08:34:10 2019 +0200

    My message

Module2/test/user/UserIT.java
Module2/pom.xml
someOtherUnrelatedFiles1
someOtherUnrelatedFiles2
```

I don't understand why `someOtherUnrelatedFiles1`and `someOtherUnrelatedFiles2` are here?

I'm using git 2.23.0, on macOS 10.14.6, and I've no hooks in `.git/hooks`.

**== Update 1**

To answer the question in the comments, here is the output of `git whatchanged`:

```
commit fdfeb44fd6fa31e3495064c06777ef4587d3c76f (HEAD -> master)
Author: Orto <Orto@abc.com>
Date:   Tue Sep 24 08:34:10 2019 +0200

    My message

:100644 100644 ed1a9bc0e 8240442a5 M    Module2/test/user/UserIT.java
:000000 100644 000000000 6845f28c4 A    Module2/pom.xml
:000000 100644 000000000 c95652dfa A    someOtherUnrelatedFiles1/test/resources/import/all.json
:000000 100644 000000000 926bfc1f9 A    someOtherUnrelatedFiles2/test/resources/import/ckan.json
```

**== Update 2**

My `~/.gitconfig`

```
    [push]
        default = simple
    [color]
        ui = auto
    [user]
        name = Orto
        email = Orto@abc.com
```

My `.git/config`

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@mygit.com:myproj/proj.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

**== Update 3==**

If I clone the repository on another location, it solves the problem, but I prefer to fix the existing repository in order to keep my unpushed branches.

**== Update 4==**

I've run:

```
git stash clear
git remote prune origin
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --aggressive --prune=now
```

bit this didn't help. The problem is maybe coming from the fact that the corresponding Gitlab project has been moved and has been renamed from `Project-Abc` to `project-abc` and that my filesystem is case insensitive (macOS). This is only an hypothesis.

Comment: What is the output of `git whatchanged`?

Comment: What’s in your global `.gitconfig` and `.git/config`?

Comment: @Ry- See my update.

Comment: Could it work to clone everything using `--mirror`?

Comment: @alexis I didn't retrieve my branches with this.

Comment: Could you delete/move your (potentially corrupted) `.git/INDEX` file and recreate it?